# Execute lambda with CreateThread

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a better way to use `CreateThread` than creating a free function each time for the sole purpose of casting  `lpParameter`?

Are there any modern alternatives to `CreateThread` for creating persistent threads?

**Edit**: Perhaps you should just use `std::async(lambda)`. I imagine that it's just implemented with `CreateThread`. Maybe the answer to this question is looking up how `std::async` is implemented (assuming it's a library feature).

```cpp
DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(
  _In_ LPVOID lpParameter
)
{
    ((MyClass*)lpParameter)->RunLoop();
}

void MyClass::LaunchThread()
{
    CreateThread( 
            NULL,                   // default security attributes
            0,                      // use default stack size  
            MyThreadFunction,       // thread function name
            this,          // argument to thread function 
            0,                      // use default creation flags 
            NULL);   // returns the thread identifier 
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::thread` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)? It's available from C++11.

Comment: As your subject suggests, you could use a lambda, but you'd still need to cast.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I was meaning without creating the free function each time, and getting the type of the lambda is not exactly straight forward.

Comment: You can use a lambda instead of a free function, but std::thread is much simpler.

Comment: The "modern" alternative to manual multi-threading is C++20 coroutines (supported since Visual Studio 2015). As long as you don't use `std::async`, things should just work the way you want them to (e.g. when using [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt)'s coroutine support).

Comment: @VLL that's only for stateless lambdas

Comment: For lambda with capturings, You can pass through `lpParameter` parameter instead.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT You can't pass a capturing lambda to `CreateThread()`, only a non-capturing lambda

Comment: @RemyLebeau Passing through `lpParameter` parameter instead of captures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mechanisms for achieving parallelism (`std::async` etc. as mentioned above).

But the modern one which is most similar to your original code with `CreateThread` is [**`std::thread`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). It can be constructed with a **global function**, **a lambda**, or a **class method** (which seems the best fit for you):

```cpp
m_thread = std::thread([this](){ RunLoop(); });  // pass a lambda
```

or

```cpp
m_thread = std::thread(&MyClass::RunLoop, this); // pass a method
```

Note that a `std::thread` starts to run (potentially) when constructed. Also note that, `std::async` does not guarantee that it will run on a separate thread and even if it does run on a thread, it could be a thread from a pool. The behaviour might not be the same as with your original `CreateThread`.

**Here's a complete example of using `std::thread` (including cancellation):**

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()  {}
    ~MyClass() { EndThread(); }

    void LaunchThread()
    {
        EndThread();    // in case it was already running
        m_bThreadShouldExit = false;
        // Start the thread with a class method:
        m_thread = std::thread(&MyClass::RunLoop, this);
    }

    void EndThread()
    {
        // Singal the thread to exit, and wait for it:
        m_bThreadShouldExit = true;
        if (m_thread.joinable())
        {
            m_thread.join();
        }
    }

    void RunLoop()
    {
        std::cout << "RunLoop started" << std::endl;
        while (!m_bThreadShouldExit)
        {
            std::cout << "RunLoop doing something ..." << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
        std::cout << "RunLoop ended" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::thread         m_thread;
    std::atomic_bool    m_bThreadShouldExit{ false };
};


int main()
{
    MyClass m;
    m.LaunchThread();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    m.EndThread();
}
```

**Possible output:**

```
RunLoop started
RunLoop doing something ...
RunLoop doing something ...
RunLoop doing something ...
RunLoop doing something ...
RunLoop doing something ...
RunLoop ended
```

Comment: I think `std::async` might be preferable to `std::thread` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: Depends on the usage. Anyway `std::thread` will give you the behavior which is [almost] identical to your original code. Note that `std::async` does not guarantee that it will run on a separate thread and even if it does run on a thread, it could be a thread from a pool. The behavior might not be the same as with your original `CreateThread`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise you could do `m_thread = std::thread([this](){ RunLoop(); });` I've only seen a lambda passed to `std::async`

Answer (score 0):

I looked in to MSVC implementation of `std::async` and they implemented it using `::Concurrency::create_task` which straight forwardly accepts a callable object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/task-parallelism-concurrency-runtime

I also looked into their implementation of `create_task`

```cpp
template<typename _Ty>
__declspec(noinline) // Ask for no inlining so that the _CAPTURE_CALLSTACK gives us the expected result
explicit task(_Ty _Param)
{
    task_options _TaskOptions;
    details::_ValidateTaskConstructorArgs<_ReturnType,_Ty>(_Param);

    _CreateImpl(_TaskOptions.get_cancellation_token()._GetImplValue(), _TaskOptions.get_scheduler());
    // Do not move the next line out of this function. It is important that _CAPTURE_CALLSTACK() evaluates to the call site of the task constructor.
    _SetTaskCreationCallstack(_CAPTURE_CALLSTACK());

    _TaskInitMaybeFunctor(_Param, decltype(details::_IsCallable(_Param,0))());
}
```

and so it turns out that launching a lambda on a new thread is quite difficult and beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, `std::thread` can be used to easily run a lambda on a new thread. See my answer update.

Comment: @wohlstad probably because I never bothered to learn the OOP interfaces to `std::thread`, `std::async`, `std::promise`, `std::future`, Microsoft's documentation and interfaces are better IMO

Comment: also the question was more about how to implement `std::thread`, but I also asked for recommendations. So "just use `std::thread`" is probably the right answer to that

Comment: Is something missing from my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645987/execute-lambda-with-createthread/73646492#73646492) in that respect ?

Comment: @wohlstad I was kind of hoping to understand how a function could take a lambda and run in with a c like api such as create thread. std::thread just offloads the problem on `Concurrency::create_task`. So I'm kind of curious about how `Concurrency::create_task` is implemented, but that rabbit hole is too deep

Comment: Maybe you can post a new question regarding it (but you'll need some concrete example, because as you probably know vague general questions are not well accepted in SO).

Answer (score 0):

std::async() and std::thread(, <args...>) are most likely internally implemented as you just did, the only exception is that lambdas **without** captures can be implicitly converted to function pointers, which pretty much can be passed straight away to CreateThread function with nullptr lpParameter.
Lambdas with capture list are pretty much syntactic sugar but internally they translate to sth like this (very simplified):

```
struct <internal_lambda_name>
{
    <capture list...> fields...;

    void operator()(<arguments...>){<code...>;}
};
```

So they pretty much translate to objects of struct type thus they need some way to store all those captures and in order to be executed on other thread with CreateThread function they need some way of ensuring that the capture list data stored in them will be available during their execution.